# Should a muslim woman meet with male colleague for condolence about his deceased relative?

Tags: hadith, sunnah, death, surat-al-fatihah

It is sunnah to visit people whose relatives passed away.

I am a muslim woman and I work with male as well as female engineers. One of my male colleague's cousin recently passed away. Should/Must I visit him (at his work station in office) and recite fatiha? Is it a deed encouraged in Islam, in my particular scenerio?

Answer (score 2):

Reciting al-Fatihah in several cases and situations in groups is an innovation which was not done by the prophet nor do we have any backup for that.

As for expressing condolence it is a highly recommended deed for both men and women.

However many on fatwa-sites they say it is disliked for a young women to go
 visit and express condolence to a men who is not a mahram.
If a lady still wants to do so she should do it in company of one of her mahrams (brother, father etc.). But note that you can do so when he is at the office as even if the time of grief is limited to a couple of days condolence might be expressed any time especially when it includes a du'a (supplication) for the deceased. And as you will be in a rather public place those reasons which might be considered for the verdict expressed above may not apply.